# Jest mocking function inside function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

So I'm trying to test if the handle submit function is being called on my form. It's hitting the condition shown below and preventing the form from being submitted. How would I go about mocking the validate function inside to return an empty object {}. This would make my form valid and then submit it as required.

Validate is defined outside of the Form component in form.jsx . I'm exporting it just as export const validate = {}

```js
    handleSubmit = event => {
        const {args} = this.state;
        let errors = validate(args);
        const isValid = isEmpty(errors)
        if(!isValid) {
            this.setState({args: args})
            event.preventDefault()
        }
        this.setState({args: args})
    }
```

My attempt

```js
    it('should handleSubmit when form is submitted', () => {
        const fakeValidate = { validate: () => true };
        const handleSubmit = jest.fn().mockImplementation((cb) => () => cb({ test: 'test' }));
        const wrapper = shallow(<Form form="test" onSubmit={handleSubmit}/>);
        wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', fakeValidate);
        expect(handleSubmit).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: This totally depends on where `validate` comes from. Which you didn't specify. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.

Comment: Apologies, i've updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to mock a function that is defined in the same module it's used. In order to be mockable, it should be either imported from another module and mocked with `jest.mock`, or be used as a method on some object and mocked with `jest.spyOn`.

Since it's used with class component, it can be defined as a method:

```
validate() {...}

handleSubmit = event => {
    ...
    let errors = this.validate(args);
    ...
}
```

And be mocked either on the class:

```
jest.spyOn(Form.prototype, 'validate').mockReturnValue(...);
```

Or component instance:

```
jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'validate').mockReturnValue(...);
```

In case `validate` is reusable or used with functional component, it should moved to another module.